# Where did the material node go in Blender 2.8?

Tags: node-editor

I recently started using Blender and there used to be a Material node if you go to "Add > Input" in the shading editor before 2.8

In Blender 2.8 I cant find it.

I am probably  be being dumb right now but I've looked for an answer everywhere and can't find one anywhere.

Anyone know the answer

Answer (score 1):

In 2.8, nodes are the constituent parts of a material. Shaders, textures, color and all the other nodes make up a material. If you want to create a new material from the shader editor, click the "New" button at the bottom or choose from existing materials to edit.
[image: Node Editor] 
Or you can click the material tab on the side and call up the material panel.
[image: Material Panel]